# batch job occasionally gets "does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission" error after multiple successful queries

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a python batch job running as a service account using bq.cmd to load multiple datastore backups.

It has been running successfully for 2 years, but recently in the middle of some runs (after multiple successful loads by the same user into the same dataset) it fails, continuously returning : "does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission".

Restarting the job, with no changes, usually succeeds.

bq.cmd load --quiet --source_format=DATASTORE_BACKUP --project_id=blah-blah --replace project-name:data_set_name.TableName gs://project-datastore-backup/2018-08-30-03_00_01/blahblah.TableName.backup_info

gcloud components are up to date.

Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

There's a [public bug with a similar issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73335423) which was resolved by recreating the service account. If you don't see any actual changes to the IAM permissions occurring in the logs, then I'd try with a [new service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts).